# FIle getting closed before getting downloaded?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, axios

Here is my `download_file()` function, Here the file should be closed after the downloading is complete, because I am `awaiting` for `axios` function **Promise** to complete.

```js
async function download_file(url, filename) {
  const file_stream = fs.createWriteStream(filename);
  await axios({
    method: "GET",
    url: url,
    responseType: "stream",
  })
    .then(function (response) {
      response.data.pipe(file_stream);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.error(error);
    });

  file_stream.close();
}

await download_file(
  "https://assets.vercel.com/image/upload/v1662090959/front/nextjs/twitter-card.png",
  "twitter.png"
);
```

But, the error is

```
node:events:505
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:377:5)
    at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:320:11)
    at Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:335:10)
    at IncomingMessage.ondata (node:internal/streams/readable:766:22)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at Readable.read (node:internal/streams/readable:539:10)
    at flow (node:internal/streams/readable:1023:34)
    at resume_ (node:internal/streams/readable:1004:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
Emitted 'error' event on WriteStream instance at:
    at WriteStream.onerror (node:internal/streams/readable:785:14)
    at WriteStream.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  code: 'ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END'
}

Node.js v18.2.0
```

It turns out that the file is getting **closed** before it is downloaded. Then, what is the point of `awating` the `axios` function.

### PLEASE NOTE:

Tell me what's wrong with my code. I want to learn what's
wrong with `axios`. And don't post fully alternative working code.
because I've already found alternative code that works fine. But, I want to know what is the problem with `awaiting` axios

Comment: You don't need `.then()` and `.catch()` if you use `async` and `await`. You can just use the `response` directly after the `await axios` call. To catch errors you need a `try catch` block. You can see this clearly in the axios documentation minimal example: https://axios-http.com/docs/example

Comment: You need to wait for the [`end`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#event-end) of the `response.data` stream before calling `file_stream.close();`, this is the problem in your code.

Comment: @GOTO 0 is correct. Specifically `response.data.on('end', ()=> { file_stream.close(); })`
@Kokodoko, correct, although I prefer a .then .catch without await but you'd need to move all the fs code inside the then.